# How can I increase the amount of time apache waits before timing out an HTTP request?

Tags: apache, http

Occasionally when a user tries to connect to the myPHP web interface on one of our web servers, the request will time out before they're prompted to login.

Is the timeout time configured on the server side or within their web browser?

Can you tell me how to increase the amount of time it waits before timing out when this happens?

Also, what logs can I look at to see why their request takes so long from time to time?

This happens on all browsers. They are connecting to myPHP in a LAMP configuration on CentOS 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you hit a limit on execution time with LAMP, it's actually [PHPs own execution timeout](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/max-ex.php) that needs to be adjusted, since both Apache's default and the browsers' defaults are much higher.

Edit: There are a couple more settings of interest to avoid certain other problems re: memory use and parsing time, they can be found [at this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/wordpress-to-wordpress-php-import-tweak/).

Comment: Where would I alter that? Thanks!

Comment: @user294746 It's in your php.ini file, called max_execution_time that sets the time in seconds (default 30 seconds usually), there's a link in the answer :)

Comment: Also remember that that time here is elapsed time.  There are lots of things that can take a long time.  If its in PHP then you are normally stuck in an infinite loop (PHP exeutes ~5M opcodes /sec) or your app is running one or more killer SQL queries (e.g. non-indexed joins).  If your script is taking more than a few seconds, then something is badly wrong. Sort that out.  Cranking the limit up to the max isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically speaking, if PHP is timing out on the defaults, you have larger problems than the timeout itself (problems connecting to the server itself, poor coding with long loops).

Joachim is right concerning the PHP timeouts though, you'll need to edit the php.ini to increase the timeout of PHP itself before troubleshooting anything else on the server; however, I would suggest trying to find out why people are hitting the timeout in the first place.

```
max_execution_time = 30;
```

Comment: Where would I begin looking to see why people are hitting the timeout? Not sure which logs I should be looking at.

Comment: I've never used Apache, wish I could provide you with more information.  If you are only trying to display a log in for the MyPHP CMS and it's timing out, you may want to troubleshoot with their message board.  The problem most likely has nothing to do with your timeouts though, those are set for a reason (not to overload your server).  I would recommend making a similar post in the MyPHP forums.